# Flutter Stripe how to set user's billing address and submit it along to create a paymentmethod?

Tags: firebase, flutter, stripe-payments

I am having some trouble setting and submitting to the Stripe server my app's customer's billing address for the Card they chose to pay with.

The code below is what I have tried but failed:

```
Future<PaymentMethod> createPaymentMethod(BuildContext context,
    Map<String, String> billingAddress, String name, String phoneNumber) async {
  StripePayment.setStripeAccount(null);
  // Here to add the credit Card
  PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod();
  print('This is in paymentMethod: ${paymentMethod.toJson()}');
  paymentMethod = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
    CardFormPaymentRequest(),
  ).then((PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
    paymentMethod.billingDetails = BillingDetails(
        address: BillingAddress(
            line1: billingAddress['Address'],
            city: billingAddress['City'],
            state: billingAddress['State'],
            postalCode: billingAddress['Zip Code']),
        name: name,
        phone: phoneNumber);
    return paymentMethod;
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('Error Card: ${e.toString()}');
  });
  paymentMethod != null
      ? print('Success')
      : AwesomeDialog(
              context: context,
              title: 'Uh oh! A wild error has appeared!',
              desc:
                  'Seems like we cant process this card. Please double check your input or try a different card',
              animType: AnimType.SCALE,
              dialogType: DialogType.WARNING,
              btnOkOnPress: () {})
          .show();
  return paymentMethod;
}
```

The payment method and payment Intent are all successful but in the `Response Body` from Stripe, I am still only getting:

```
 "billing_details": {
      "address": {
        "city": null,
        "country": "US",
        "line1": null,
        "line2": null,
        "postal_code": null,
        "state": null
      },
      "email": null,
      "name": null,
      "phone": null
    },
```

On my Response POST body I am only having:

```
{
  "amount": "5178",
  "currency": "usd",
  "payment_method": "some_payment_method_here",
  "confirm": "true",
  "confirmation_method": "manual",
  "off_session": "false"
}
```

How should I set my code such that I have finally have the user's billing address in the Response Body so that I can have:

```
"billing_details": {
      "address": {
        "city": "Sesame Town",
        "country": "US",
        "line1": "123 Sesame Street",
        "line2": null,
        "postal_code": 12345,
        "state": "Sesame State"
      },
      "email": "mayorOfSesameStreet@email.com",
      "name": "Mayor Sesame",
      "phone": 8889990000
    },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remember firestore is case sensitive, could you try to get the data using lowercase on your code? e.g. 'address' instead ''Address'

Comment: The Response Body and POST are from and to Stripe not firestore.

Answer (score 3):

I’m assuming you’re using the stripe_payment package (https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment)? If you already have the customer’s billing address, you can pre-fill it by setting `CardFormPaymentRequest.prefilledInformation.billingAddress` (https://pub.dev/documentation/stripe_payment/latest/stripe_payment/CardFormPaymentRequest-class.html). Here’s how it would look in your code:

```
PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod();
CardFormPaymentRequest req = CardFormPaymentRequest(
    prefilledInformation: PrefilledInformation (
        billingAddress: BillingAddress(
            line1: billingAddress['Address'],
            city: billingAddress['City'],
            state: billingAddress['State'],
            postalCode: billingAddress['Zip Code'],
            name: name)));
paymentMethod = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(req).then((PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
    return paymentMethod;
}).catchError((e) {
    print('Error Card: ${e.toString()}');
});
```

Comment: Hey Amanda! Thanks for the reply. I have tried your solution however, I am still getting the same result: {created: 1601000055.0, id: pm_something_here_that_is_replaced, livemode: false, type: card, billingDetails: {address: {country: US}}, card: {addressLine1: null, addressLine2: null, brand: visa, country: US, expMonth: 4, expYear: 2024, funding: credit, last4: 4242}}

Comment: Did a bit of digging - do you happen to be using Android? It looks like setting `prefilledInformation` is limited to iOS only https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/issues/185

Comment: That's good information to know! Im actually using the iOS simulator on my computer for testing at the moment

Comment: Hmm.. I'm all out of ideas. Only thing I can think to try is making sure the `billingAddress` map you pass in to your `createPaymentMethod()` function is what you expect it to be